# Materials become pure white with no shading when modified through code | Godot C#

Tags: c#, godot, godot4, materials

I have a `PackedScene` that I am instantiating through code. All that that scene has is a single `MeshInstance3D` with a default `StandardMaterial3D`.

From the code, after instantiating I try and modify the `AlbedoColor` of the `MeshInstance3D`. However, no matter what I seem to do, the material comes in as pure white with no shading.

[image]

If I manually add a material either to the `MeshInstance3D` directly or through either the Surface Material Override or `Geometry.MaterialOvrride` in the inspector, everything works as expected and materials have proper shading. However, as soon as I add or modify a material through code, it immediately breaks and looks like the image above.
I've tried various approaches through code, all outlined below:

**Direct access to mesh material**

```cs
var orb = _orbResource.Instantiate<Orb>();
if (orb.Mesh.SurfaceGetMaterial(0) is StandardMaterial3D material)
{
    material.AlbedoColor = _color;
    orb.Mesh.SurfaceSetMaterial(0, material);
}
```

**Direct access to Override Material**

```cs
var orb = _orbResource.Instantiate<Orb>();
if (orb.MaterialOverride is not StandardMaterial3D material)
{
    throw new NullReferenceException("The orb did not have a material override");
}

material.AlbedoColor = _color;
        
orb.MaterialOverride = material;
```

**New Override Material**

```cs
var orb = _orbResource.Instantiate<Orb>();
var material = new StandardMaterial3D();
material.AlbedoColor = _color;
        
orb.MaterialOverride = material;
```

I've tried various combinations of the above. It doesn't change even if I directly set the material again after modifying it. No matter what though, if I modify the `AlbedoColor`, it always turns to full white with no shading. I've authenticated the colors as well. I'm seriously at a loss as to what could be happening but I feel like it's something simple I just overlooked.

I'm new to Godot so it's probably some engine-specific thing I missed.

**Edit 1**

As @Theraot mentioned, I tried to do the same thing in a new project and it resulted in the same issue. Take a look at the image below.

[image]

All of these balls are `MeshInstance3D`s with their own unique sphere mesh instance. The sphere on the bottom center is the one I am modifying via code. No matter how I do it, it always ends up unlit and pure white. The mesh on the left has a material directly on the mesh. The sphere on the right has no material. And the sphere on the top has a material override. They all work just fine unless I modify them via code. Strange.

My lighting setup is a box around the spheres with a point light.

It's also important to say that I can create and assign materials and they seem to work fine. However, as soon as I modify any property, they break.

Comment: The code looks correct to me. I don't know what the issue could be... My suggestion is to try to reproduce the problem in a new project, you might notice something you did or didn't do in the process. Addendum: and if not, then you have a project you can send on github to report this as a bug.

Comment: @Theraot I tried with a new project as you suggested. Same issue. See Edit 1 in the modified question.

Comment: Well, I still don't know what's up. I've seen something like this with shader errors, but you are using the standard material, so I'm thinking it is a bug. You can report it as such here: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as suspected, the answer was something super simple. I was assigning colors incorrectly. When creating a color, the correct way to do so is like `var color = new Color(0.1f, 1f, 0.45f, 0.2f);`, where everything is in the range 0f - 1f. I, however, was trying to do something like `var color = new Color(100, 24, 255, 40);` which is incorrect. So, when the value was being assigned it was WAY out of range of valid colors which resulted in the weird effect. Not sure what I was thinking, but I'm glad I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can try cloning material for each orb

```
var orb = (Orb)_orbResource.Instance();
var meshInstance = (MeshInstance3D)orb.GetNode("MeshInstance");
var material = (StandardMaterial3D)meshInstance.GetSurfaceMaterial(0).Duplicate();
material.AlbedoColor = _color;
meshInstance.SurfaceSetMaterial(0, material);
```

also in your aproach of
**New override mateiral**
I would suggest using getnode() so you make sure you are adding the material to the hierarchy OBJ(Node)

```
var orb = (Orb)_orbResource.Instance();
var material = new StandardMaterial3D();
material.AlbedoColor = _color;
var meshInstance = (MeshInstance3D)orb.GetNode("MeshInstance");
meshInstance.SurfaceSetMaterial(0, material);
```

Please make sure your node is MeshInstance or whatever your orb's MeshInstance3D is named in the scene

Comment: I have tried the duplication method with all the previous material methods as well to no avail. I'll try explicitly getting the `MeshInstance3D` and see if that helps.

Comment: Since the orb itself is a MeshInstance3D, I couldn't use `GetNode` on it. However, I did add a new `MeshInstance3D` to the orb as a child and modified its material instead. Same issues. I even went as far as starting an entirely new project and simply adding a new Material via script and no matter how I do it, always ends up unlit and pure white.